# "segmentation fault : 11" in generic class

Tags: swift, generics, segmentation-fault, swift4

I'm trying to create a simple type erasure struct in Swift 4:

```
protocol DataProvider
{
  associatedtype ItemType

  subscript(index: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}

struct AnyDataProvider<providerType: DataProvider> : DataProvider
{
  private var _subscript: (_ index: Int) -> providerType.ItemType

  init<P : DataProvider>(_ base: P) where P.ItemType == providerType.ItemType
  {
    _subscript = base.subscript
  }

  subscript(index: Int) -> providerType.ItemType
  {
    return _subscript(index)
  }
}
```

But I am getting a segmentation fault : 11 on the line that declares the initialiser.

Any ideas, apart from reporting it as a bug?

Comment: This isn't type-erased. Your `AnyDataProvider` is parameterized by a `DataProvider`. All you're doing is trying to make it possible to treat one `DataProvider` as if it's a different one (with no obvious benefit, since the types are the same). If you really want to erase the `DataProvider`, then your `AnyDataProvider` should be parameterized by the `ItemType` itself, not by a `DataProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Yesss!

The problem is that you cannot assign a subscript "method" to a closure reference.

To achieve this, Slava Pestov from Apple showed me the trick of assigning an anonymous closure, which calls the subscript.

Here is the finished code :

```
protocol DataProvider
{
  associatedtype ItemType

  subscript(index: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}

struct AnyDataProvider<itemType> : DataProvider
{
  private let _subscript: (Int) -> itemType

  subscript(index: Int) -> itemType
  {
    return _subscript(index)
  }

  init<providerType : DataProvider>(_ base: providerType) where providerType.ItemType == itemType
  {
    _subscript = { base[$0] }
  }
}
```